# Restrict firebase functions only from my app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an app that uses firebase functions. I want users to only be able to execute these functions only from my app and not outside of it, is this possible? I am making them have to authenticate first to use these functions. I'm doing it this way:

```
exports.myFunction = onCall( (request) => {

  if (request.auth) {

    // ...

  } else {

    return { message: 'Access prohibited' };

  }

});
```

Now I have two specific questions:

1. Any user could authenticate and get the verification token and run the function from outside my application right? If so, how can I prevent this? Is it possible to restrict that only these functions can be executed only from my app? I read that with App Check this can be controlled, but I still don't understand it well. If so, could you guide me better?
2. From the Google Cloud / Cloud Functions console the function caller is set by default to `allUsers`, should I change it? This has some relevance to the goal of restricting the function to run only from my app

Comment: 1) You can't prevent this. You can only take steps to prevent abusive behavior from a user that invokes your function. That's what App Check helps with, but it is not 100% effective, per the documentation. 2) allUsers permission is required for functions that don't require GCP service accounts for authentication (Firebase end users do not use service accounts, and it does not apply to functions that need to be invoked by users of web and mobile apps).